# How to print all modelnames with count number related to its brandname in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel-5

working with laravel 5.6 and mysql. I have following table name as `vehicles`

```
id  name  categoryname  brandname    model
1   juy   car           toyota       121
2   gty   van           nissan       caravan
3   bgh   car           bmw          520d
4   hyu   van           ford         max
5   nhj   car           toyota       121
6   gtr   car           toyota       corolla
7   gtr   van           nissan       caravan
```

i am using following controller function to display categorynames with bransnames

```
public function filterbrand ()
    {
        $vehicles = DB::table('vehicles')
                    ->orderBy('categoryname', 'asc')
                    ->get();

                  return view('vehicles.brand')->withVehicles($vehicles);
```

and use following blade file to show data

```
<?php $cat = ""; ?>
@foreach($vehicles->unique('brandname') as $vehicle)
   @if($vehicle->categoryname != $cat )
            <?php $cat = $vehicle->categoryname; ?>
             {{$cat}}
            <br><br>
     @endif
     <ul>
    <li>{{$vehicle->brandname}}</li> <br>

  </ul>
@endforeach
```

this is printing this types outputs

car
toyota
bmw

van
nissan
ford

but now I need print also modelnames with its counting like this

car
toyota
121 (2)
corolla (1)
bmw
520d (1)

van
nissan
carvan (2) 
ford
max (1)

How can I modify my blade or controller for this new requirements?

Comment: No any ideas?..

Comment: I need some help here...

Comment: Have a look at [Aggregates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#aggregates) and [Grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) in the laravel query builder doc. In SQLite, for example, you would want "SELECT categoryname, brandname, model, count(*) from vehicles GROUP BY categoryname, brandname,model"